# Using typeScript to get a local JSON file. I am getting a cross origin err in the static pages

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am using typeScript to get a local JSON file. I am getting a cross-origin error in the static pages.
Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
//   // all of your code goes in here
//   // it runs after the DOM is built
function loadJSON(path, success, error) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        if (success) success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      } else {
        if (error) error(xhr);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", path, true);
  xhr.send();
}

loadJSON(
  "../dataBase/electrical.json",
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    function getSgItem() {
      let sg = "";

      data.forEach(function(item) {
        sg += `
                <div class="data">
                    <div class="image">
                    <img src="../images/electrical/scherer01.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="dataContent">
                    <h2>${item.sgice}</h2>
                    <h1>${item.name}</h1>
                    <div class="button">
                        <div class="buttonInfo">
                        <h3>SHIPS#</h3>
                        <h3>${item.ships}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <button>
                        <a href=${item.link}>CLICK HERE</a>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
      });
      document.getElementById("sg").innerHTML = sg;
    }

    getSgItem();
  },
  function(xhr) {
    console.error(xhr);
  }
);
}
```

I need to run it as a static page for the internal server for the company. Is there a way to fix this?

Using vs code it works fine when I right click and open with live server.

Thanks so much.

Comment: what error are you getting? It won't be due to typescript but due to CORS I imagine

Comment: My error:

jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Andre/Documents/Programing/powerIE/dist/dataBase/electrical.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https.